# Ajuda a fazer uma condição em php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, if

Eu tenho aqui o meu código php para que se possa eliminar o cliente, mas so elimina quando se escreve o nome do cliente(que esta no html). mas não sei fazeer a condição caso alguém escreva um nome de um cliente que nao esteja na base de dados. E também nao entendo quando eu meto um nome atoa ele a mesma da a mensagem de cliente apagado :/ , nao faz o else

```
   <script language="javascript">
<!--
function myFunction(a) {
    alert(a);
}

</script>

<?php

ini_set ('default_charset','utf-8');

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bd_calcadocharme");

$id=$_GET['id'];

$sql="DELETE FROM encomenda WHERE id='$id'";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

if ($result){
    echo "<script> myFunction('Cliente eliminado com sucesso'); </script>";
    header('refresh:0 ; url=pedir_rese.html'); }
else{
    echo "<script> myFunction('Erro ao tentar eliminar o registo na base de dados!'); </script>";
    header('refresh:0 ; url=pedir_rese.html');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Seu `if` está errado, ele só verifica se existe o objeto e não quantas linhas foram modificadas.

No seu caso eu faria

```
$sql="DELETE FROM encomenda WHERE id='$id'";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt) > 0)
    {
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        echo "<script> myFunction('Cliente eliminado com sucesso'); </script>";
        header('refresh:0 ; url=pedir_rese.html'); }
    }
    else
    {
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        echo "<script> myFunction('Erro ao tentar eliminar o registo na base de dados!'); </script>";
        header('refresh:0 ; url=pedir_rese.html');
    } 
}
```

Sobre seu problema com informar um usuário que não existe depende muito do código que está enviando a requisição, uma solução é criar um `dropdown` com apenas os clientes existentes no banco e ele seleciona qual ele quer eliminar. Ou então mudar sua mensagem de `Erro ao tentar eliminar o registo na base de dados!` para `Nenhum usuário com esse nome encontrado!`.

Answer (score 0):

Existem duas opções para você utilizar.

**OPÇÃO 1**

Você pode realizar uma pesquisa anteriormente ao banco de dados, verificando se o cliente existe. Se existir o cliente exclui, caso contrário, mostra a mensagem que ocorreu "erro", pois ele não existe.

```
$sqlSelect = "SELECT id FROM encomenda WHERE id='$id'";
$data = [];
$result = false;

if($res = mysqli_query($link, $sqlSelect)) {
    while($return = mysqli_fetch_object($res)) {
        $data[] = $return;
    }
}

if(!empty($data)) {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM encomenda WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
}

if ($result){
    echo " myFunction('Cliente eliminado com sucesso'); ";
    header('refresh:0 ; url=pedir_rese.html'); 
} else {
    echo " myFunction('Erro ao tentar eliminar o registo na base de dados!'); ";
    header('refresh:0 ; url=pedir_rese.html');
}
```

**OPÇÃO 2**

Verificar quantas linhas foram afetadas na última execução, se for maior que 0, então pelo menos um registro foi excluído. Neste caso o seu cliente foi excluído.

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM encomenda WHERE id='$id'";

mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (mysqli_affected_rows($link) > 0){
    echo " myFunction('Cliente eliminado com sucesso'); ";
    header('refresh:0 ; url=pedir_rese.html'); 
} else {
    echo " myFunction('Erro ao tentar eliminar o registo na base de dados!'); ";
    header('refresh:0 ; url=pedir_rese.html');
}
```